# Function key reset by Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have just finished fixing a function (an HTTP trigger) that stopped working due to the [deployment of Azure Functions Runtime 2.0.12050-alpha](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/129). The error shown in the portal was `The binding type(s) 'someType' are not registered`.

After implementing a few changes (e.g. adding a reference to Azure Storage extension, `ILogger` instead of `TraceWriter`), the function started to work locally again, but my application was still failing.

After some poking around, I noticed that the function key has changed. The value was different than the one stored in the settings of the web app that was calling the function. I set the new value there and everything started to work fine.

Is it possible that the function key was reset without my knowledge?
(It's a small side project and I'm the only developer.)

Is it because of the new Functions Runtime deployment or are the keys reset periodically?

Comment: Is it a [Application settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings), could you tell us the name of the settings that changed?

Comment: It was a custom setting under `Application settings`. You can see my [code at GitHub](https://github.com/chopeen/last-fm-not-mine-alert-web/blob/9cbf3d26594e3c8aed80b2bafbc78a66aeab8f39/Pages/Index.cshtml.cs#L53).

Comment: I also had a problem with SendGrid integration, although in this case I cannot confirm the key was changed, because - once generated - the SG key cannot be displayed again. However, I removed the old key, created a new one and the emails are now sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Changes to Key Management in Functions V2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Changes-to-Key-Management-in-Functions-V2).

Azure Functions currently supports two key storage mechanisms: file system and blob storage.

File system was always used to store secrets for both 1.x and 2.x runtime. For 2.x, begin with runtime [2.0.12050-alpha](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/129), function secrets are stored in blob storage (`AzureWebJobsStorage` in Application settings) by default, users can switch to files by setting the `AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType` app setting to `files`.

To make the transition work smoothly, Function team implemented a temporary key migration code path that would automatically copy the secrets from the file system to blob storage. **BUT** this internal method is not enabled from runtime `2.0.12115` as it was somewhat error prone.

This means:

If you pinged your function runtime (set `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` to minor version <= `2.0.11961-alpha`) before `2.0.12050-alpha` was deployed and release the ping (change `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` to major version `~2`) after `2.0.12115` was deployed (right now it's `2.0.12134`), your function keys are expected to be changed.

Else runtime is upgraded automatically and Function app created before `2.0.1250` should benefit from the secret migration code and has the consistent keys.

I always leave runtime to major version (`beta` before 2.x is GA and `~2` after) and I can confirm my keys are not influenced. As for SendGrid API key, it's controlled by SendGrid service other than Azure hence can't be influenced. BTW my SendGrid API key generated months ago still works right now.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the keys were reset due to **changing the storage account** associated with my function app.

Specifically, while I was fixing the function code for environment X, I noticed that the `AzureWebJobsStorage` environment variable was pointing at the storage account associated with environment Y and changed it.

Per @jerry-liu's comments, since 2.x function secrets are stored in blob storage, changing the associated blob storage account effectively "reset" your function keys.